# HorizontalStretch for custom TabControl TabItem Header items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following `TabControl` with a custom `ItemTemplate` (added `ScrollViewer` functionality). Now I would like to horizontal stretch the (green/red) `Grid` to use the full width. I have already tried all `HorizontalAlignment` or `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties in `Grid`, `ScrollViewer` or `TabPanel` .

But I'm actually stucked how to solve it.

[image]

```cs
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" TabStripPlacement="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Collection}" SelectedIndex="0">
    <!-- Vertical TabItems with ScrollViewer -->
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="4" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
    <!-- Define TabItem Header -->
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Header.Page}"/>
                    <Run Text="/"/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Header.PageEnd}"/>
                    <Run Text=" - "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Header.ProjectNumber}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckResult.CheckStatus}" Value="{x:Static macros:ECheckStatus.Unchecked}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckResult.CheckStatus}" Value="{x:Static macros:ECheckStatus.Io}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckResult.CheckStatus}" Value="{x:Static macros:ECheckStatus.Warning}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CheckResult.CheckStatus}" Value="{x:Static macros:ECheckStatus.Error}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Grid" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `Grid` to `Stretch`. Here is an example how to do it

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

This should stretch the grid horizontally to fill the available space

Comment: As mentioned above, I have already tried this without success.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are targeting the item container's content instead of the container itself.

To improve performance you should avoid using `Run` to define the text of the `TextBlock`. Instead implement a `IValueConverter` to compose the `string`.

To solve the issue you must override the the template of the `TabItem` and implement the triggers inside the `ControlTemplate`:

```xml
<TabControl>
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

          <!-- The DataContext of the TabItem is the data item -->
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CheckResult.CheckStatus}" 
                           Value="{x:Static macros:ECheckStatus.Io}"> 
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="LightGreen" />
              </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

If you want to avoid to override the visual states of the `TabItem` control you can consider to implement the triggers in the `Style.Triggers` instead. Note that this limits the possibilities as those triggers will be overridden by the internal visual state manager. You get most flexibility by overriding the default template like in the example above.